# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/method/annotation/support/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/method/annotation/support/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) [spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:609) [spring-web-servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:571) [spring-web-servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:623) [spring-web-servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:491) [spring-web-servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:432) [spring-web-servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133) [spring-web-servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.M2]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

Comment: Please be so kind to describe the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Class RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver is in org.springframework.web.method.annotation package and not in org.springframework.web.method.annotation.support package. Please describe your issue in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

check your have spring-web.jar in your project